# Unable to figure out Rails api json response for nested attributes and file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, curl, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-api

Hi everyone. I am using Rails 4, and i am working on api. Below are my code.

**Api::DocumentsController**

```
class Api::DocumentsController < Api::BaseController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  respond_to :json, :xml

 def create
   @document = Document.new(document_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
   @signers = current_user.signers

   @signer_ids = params[:signer_ids]

  if @document.save
    @document.create_activity action: :create, recipient: current_user, owner: current_user, custom_field: request.remote_ip

    if @signer_ids.present?
     @signer_ids.each do |id|
      unless id.blank?
        DocumentSigner.find_or_create_by(document_id: @document.id, signer_id: id)
      end
    end
  end

    @response_message = {:message => "Your document has been saved.", :document => @document}
else
    @response_message = {:message => "Document creation failed. Please try again!"}
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.json {
    render json: @response_message
  }
end
end

  private
    def document_params
     params.require(:document).permit(:document_name, :document, :email_body, :user_id, {:signers_attributes => [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :is_clicked, :document_id, :user_id, :_destroy]})
    end
 end
```

When i save document without api calls, i have following output.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0gVL8K5nfsQfy/AmBqDQpzTF4aHs7uASSof4b11r4ME=", "document"=>{"document"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000006f63398 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150214-11121-1004vyd>, @original_filename="mozilla.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document[document]\"; filename=\"mozilla.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">, "document_name"=>"my document", "signers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "is_clicked"=>"true", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1423910618865"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "is_clicked"=>"true", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "email_body"=>"this is the message value"}, "signer_ids"=>["1", "3"], "commit"=>"Open Document", "payment"=>{"is_payment_with_signature"=>"false", "signer_id"=>"", "payment_amount"=>""}}
```

Document model with pdf upload feature. Document will have many signers and accepts nested attributes for signers.

And signers_attributes which is a nested attributes in document which will save user_id, is_clicked, email_body, etc.

Now i am not able to access this create action through curl command for nested attributes. Can anyone please help me in creating curl command for my create action including signers nested attributes and pdf upload.

```
curl -X POST -F document=/home/rails/Documents/mozilla.pdf -F 'document[:name]=document nameeee &api_key=-pq45wMEMgjtP5v5GUw3'  http://localhost:3000/api/documents.json
```

Comment: I solved it. Everything was fine. Data required for nested attributes, i passed through params, it works perfect. And now document upload also working fine.